# Quiero que me aparezca el codigo html del archivo mant.js en en navegador a través del archivo app.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, modulos

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código debe ir _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es directamente cambiar tu archivo mant.js y escribirlo directamente en HTML. Luego en tu archivo app.js con ayuda de express puedes mostrar tu página en el navegador.
Como buena práctica también almacena tu archivo .html dentro de una carpeta llamada "public"

Tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

--mant.html--

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mantenimientos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Mantenimientos</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

--app.js--

```
import express from 'express'
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';



const app = express()
app.use(express.json());

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);
const publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');

app.use(express.static(publicPath))

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/mant.html')
});

app.listen(1000)
console.log("Servidor corriendo en el puerto 1000")
```

Espero te sirva la ayuda ;)